# jquery rotating button incrementally

Tags: jquery, css, rotatetransform

hey I'm trying to animate the rotation of a button 45 degrees every time it's clicked, and I can't get my function to work, this is what I have so far:

```
function increaseAngle(elem) {
    var oldAngle = $(elem).data('angle');
    var newAngle = oldAngle + 45;
    $(elem)
        .css("-webkit-transform", "rotateZ(" + newAngle + "deg)")
        .data('angle', newAngle);
}

$(".info_btn")
    .css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out")
    .data('angle', 0);
    .toggle(function() {
        increaseAngle(this);
    }, function() {
        increaseAngle(this);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    .data('angle', 0);
    .toggle(function() {
```

If you're trying to chain your functions, that semicolon shouldn't be there.

Your code [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/yJQp5/2/), you just need a minor adjustment to how you're calling it. Toggle will hide the element, so use the click event instead.

```
$(".info_btn")
  .css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out")
  .data('angle', 0)
  .click(function() {
      increaseAngle(this);
});
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/obugig/3/edit  so if I take that away, the image disappears, http://jsbin.com/obugig/3/edit

Comment: so the second part was to try to animate the rotation using css

Comment: @loriensleafs, you're calling toggle. Toggle will hide the element the way you are calling it. Why not just use the click event? See the updated link.